# Request to make the tag winter be a synonym for cold-weather?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I can't make synonyms, but could someone with mod powers change the winter tag to be a synonym for [cold-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-weather).

Winter can mean different things for different locations on the globe, but what is common is how to enjoy / survive in the outdoors when the temperature is cold.

Also, I would like to propose either one or two more tags for more extreme weather.

- freezing-weather (or subzero-weather)
- arctic-weather (for temperatures where degrees C and degrees F start to align - more than 20 below)

Are there any established temperature ranges from reputable outdoors schools like NOLS or other?

(I'm from Minnesota, so we have lots of experience with the many ranges of cold but I don't want to saturate the tags with too fine of a line for the rest of the audience)

Answer (score 8):

Playing devil's advocate, but there could be scenarios when it's not just about cold weather:

- Questions about the different plants available in winter to summer
- Questions about navigation by stars and how they differ in the winter
- Questions about certain events that might be organised in the winter

OK, that last one especially is dubious, but my point is there can be situations when [winter](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter) would be used differently from [cold-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-weather). Instead, I'd propose that we edit the questions with [winter](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter) to be [cold-weather](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-weather) if they're specifically about the cold, and don't put them as synonyms right away in case questions specifically to do with winter in some other way do crop up.